# Drawing line between two points from another CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, csv, polyline-creation

I have two large CSV files, one that defines the location of each point as:

| point | lat | lon | attribute 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

And another that has data on what lines exist between them

| point A | point B | attribute 2 | attribute 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Since the second CSV does not have lat/lon coordinates, I cannot map them. I've considered using `LINESTRING`, but the dataset is too big to manually compute the linestring between 2 points.

Is there any way to 'assign' the coordinates from the first CSV to the second?

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. Can you add a sample of your csv files to your question?

Comment: It's unclear if `attribute1` is the same used in `point A/B`, but if it is, then yes, it's possible, though probably not necessary if you're constructing a line between them.

Answer (score 3):

If your points have unique IDs, which match between the CSV files, you may use `join attributestable` to add the coordinates from the first CSV to the second CSV twice. Then you can use `make_line()` to create the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would I use QGIS's python console to do this?

Comment: Nope, this is a tool, and an expression from the field calculator @lizard.

Answer (score 2):

Does your "point" from the first CSV and "point A" "point B" from the second CSV  could be used for joining the two table ?

If so you should be able to join the table with coordinate to the second one. Do it two time, a first joint with "point A" and "point " to get lat A / lon A then join again but with "point B" and "point" to get lat B / lon B

As you now have a table with start and end point coordinate you could use geometry generator or the Geometry by expression tool to create your line